# resize an image without UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

I want to resize an image without UIScrollView in iPhone application.

I want to use touchesMoved. How to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually load the image in a UIWebView instead of UIImageView, then you automatically get zoom/resize behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the transform property of your UIImageView.